# SSH Error: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: macos, ssh, amazon-ec2, openssh

When trying to connect to EC2 over SSH I get the following error:

```
joshua-scotts-macbook-pro:.ec2 joshuascott$ ssh -v -i OFMoodle root@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8l 5 Nov 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file OFMoodle type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.7 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/joshuascott/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: pk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.pem
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: OFMoodle
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I am completely at a loss. I have several other instances that I can connect to with out any problem.

Comment: more appropriate for serverfault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I'd make sure the user is really *root* and not *ubuntu* or *ec2-user*.

Otherwise, it could be that the permissions on `.ssh/` and `.ssh/authorized_keys` are *borked*.

Comment: SSH doesn’t like it if your home or ~/.ssh directories have group write permissions. Your home directory should be writable only by you, ~/.ssh should be 700, and authorized_keys should be 600 [_Source_](http://recursive-design.com/blog/2010/09/14/ssh-authentication-refused/)